# Setting Viewport width in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch, viewport, sencha-touch-2, web-applications

My Sencha Touch 2 app works perfectly on my desktop browser but when I test it on the iPhone the viewport is not set correctly.
My app has a fixed layout with a width of 640 Pixel. On iPhone 3G, only half of the app is seen. Inspecting the generated html I can see multiple "viewport" declarations in the `<head>` section, e.g.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">
```

I figured I have to set the viewport width to 640 and inserted this code at the end of the `<head>` section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content = "width=640,initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" />
```

but to no avail. Why does Sencha Touch insert multiple viewport declarations? How can I override it? Or what do I have to do to display the app in full width?

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding meta tag, the width property controls the size of the viewport. It can be set to a specific number of pixels like width=600 or to the special value device-width value which is the width of the screen in CSS pixels at a scale of 100%.

Regarding your problem, there may be some content which might crossing the width of device, Either you need to add the scroll bars or need to take inbuilt controls of sencha.